# Is it fair to get so many downvotes in such a short amount of time?

Tags: support, downvotes

I just asked a question. (I believe it is a normal question)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400940/should-we-disable-javascript-in-browsers-by-default-what-are-our-security-re

I got 9 downvotes.

I didn't even have time or the possibility to comment on what people said.
I couldn't delete my question either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is deleted now (by the community). Do you want support or do you want to discuss fairness?

Comment: And yes, something as blatantly off-topic as that deserves that many downvotes in such a short amount of time (it has nothing to do with programming).

Comment: Because an ungrounded fear ("JavaScript is dangerous, why is it enabled by default?") has no place on a community for programming enthusiasts and professionals. There are many ways to re-word that question into something more informed and less ... offensive to the reader.

Comment: Quote: "At least someone has some brains arround here!"  Clearly you got heavily downvoted for that spelling mistake.

Answer (score 15):

Yes it is. Questions that don't belong on the site (for reasons of scope, quality, or both) can attract downvotes and are likely to be closed and even deleted.

There is no minimum amount of time required for this to happen. You had an infinite amount of time before asking your question. But once you decide to post it, it does get evaluated as is. The closure reason will provide you with the information you need. As do several of the comments.

Your subsequent "comments" at the bottom of your question in the various revisions don't really help you either. Some of the downvotes might well have been given because of those.

So overall, there's nothing really out of the ordinary here.